# How to check if an entry already exists inside a table (SQL using Python)

Tags: python, sql, database

I am new to this. I've established a connection to my Oracle database using cx_Oracle. Say that I have a table named "student" with the following infos: "name","age","student_number","adress". Now i'm looking into inserting another row to the table. How do I check if student_number 6 already exist? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend you to take a look at the basics of SQL...

```
SELECT * FROM "student" WHERE "student_number" = 6
```

Comment: How do I do this in Python though?